# Minecraft Pocket Edition Multiplayer

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I wanted to connect to a Lifeboat server in Minecraft PE. I tried  of all them, but each time the loading stops at the middle, it shows 'Building Terrain', but it never loads! By never I mean like couple hours and it kept at the same loading level.

I tried on two versions in two different devices on the same wifi so it's not my installation or device. Can I do anything to make it work?

Answer (score -1):

Different versions of IOS could be an issue for you. If you're in ios7 and another player is in ios8 you could have issues caused by a lacking in your two different softwares. All I can say is try a different server